# CSS for dividers between list items

Tags: css, padding, margin

I have the following HTML/CSS code for a list which I have played around with so it looks the same in all browsers...

```
<div>
    <ul>  
        <li><a href='#'>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Item 3</a></li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

​
CSS:

```
div {
    width:290px;
}
ul {
    padding:0 15px;
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#999;
}

ul li {
    padding:5px;
    margin:2px 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
    list-style-position:inside;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
    list-style-type:circle;
}

ul li:hover {
    background-color:#EEE;
}

ul li a {
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 238px;
}​
```

On hover, the list item background color changes to grey and there is a 2 pixel white gap at the top before each divider.

Where I have a problem is getting this 2 pixel gap at the bottom of each list item as well as at the top.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

replace the margins to this:

```
ul li {
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure my question was all that clear... I want the 2px white gap at the top AND the bottom...

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse you define `margin:2px 0;` in your LI. Remove that `margin`.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/d8gNJ/

Comment: Not sure my question was all that clear... I want the 2px white gap at the top AND the bottom...

Answer (score 0):

@Tom: Update your css at ul li hover

```
ul li:hover {
    background-color:#EEE;
    padding-top:2px; 
}
```

You can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/6DXx6/3/

Let me know if it is what you want